# SPARC cpu VS thread VS core

Tags: solaris, sparc

I'm not sure if anyone has really asked this in this forum before. Initial search in the form didn't really dig out substantial info.
Trying to pace together some information from a product licensing view. Where can i find information and the co-relation of :

CPU/CORE/THREADS/PROCESSORS

Where will i be able to find the info.

cheers
ops

Comment: uh what product are you talking about

Comment: oracle DB and DB2 :|

Answer (score 1):

A UltraSPARC T series processor has multiple cores, each core has multiple threads (e.g. 16 cores and 128 threads per [UltraSPARC T5 chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC_T5)), and each thread is reported as a vCPU by the OS.

Depending on the software, the licensing might be per core and there might be a core factor that depends on the CPU model.

Have a look to the [official Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/contracts/license-service-agreement/index.html) for up to date and accurate details.